# How to filter and map Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

The original array has several objects within it, each of these objects has three properties (timestamp, name and age).

If multiple timestamps in a row are 15 minutes apart, they will be grouped into the same object. Afterwards, a new property called end will be added, which will be the timestamp value of the last element of this group plus 15 minutes.

If there are not several elements in a row with a difference of 15 minutes between them, the end property will have the timestamp plus 15 minutes as a value.

This is my current code:

```js
const data = [
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:15:00+0000',
        name: 'John',
        age: 25,
    },
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:30:00+0000',
        name: 'John',
        age: 25,
    },
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:45:00+0000',
        name: 'John',
        age: 25,
    },
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T15:45:00+0000',
        name: 'John',
        age: 25,
    },
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:15:00+0000',
        name: 'Anne',
        age: 32,
    },
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:30:00+0000',
        name: 'Anne',
        age: 32,
    },
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:45:00+0000',
        name: 'Anne',
        age: 32,
    },
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T15:45:00+0000',
        name: 'Anne',
        age: 32,
    },
]

const newArray = data.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    const end = new Date(Date.parse(current.timestamp) + 15 * 60 * 1000)
    if (accumulator.length === 0) {
        accumulator.push({
            ...current,
            end,
        })
    } else {
        const last = accumulator[accumulator.length - 1]
        if (last.name === current.name && last.age === current.age) {
            last.end = end
        } else {
            accumulator.push({
                ...current,
                end,
            })
        }
    }
    return accumulator
}, [])

console.log(newArray)
```

However the end result of my code is not exactly what I want. I would like my result to be like this:

```js
[
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:15:00+0000',
        name: 'John',
        age: 25,
        end: '2021-11-23T15:00:00+0000'
    },
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T15:45:00+0000',
        name: 'John',
        age: 25,
        end: '2021-11-23T16:00:00+0000'
    },
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:15:00+0000',
        name: 'Anne',
        age: 32,
        end: '2021-11-23T15:00:00+0000'
    },
    {
        timestamp: '2021-11-23T15:45:00+0000',
        name: 'Anne',
        age: 32,
        end: '2021-11-23T16:00:00+0000'
    }
]
```

Comment: Why does the output have half the number of objects than that of the input?

Comment: @ze00ne I did not understand the question. I would like to do this so it would be simpler for me to work with the data.

Comment: The end result has 4 objects `{}` and the original array has 8 objects `{}`...why?

Comment: Just a question, are you asking why I want to go from 8 objects to 4? @zer00ne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search for the last interval and update `end` if found. Otherwise add a new object.

```js
const data = [{ timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:15:00+0000', name: 'John', age: 25 }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:30:00+0000', name: 'John', age: 25 }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:45:00+0000', name: 'John', age: 25 }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T15:45:00+0000', name: 'John', age: 25 }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:15:00+0000', name: 'Anne', age: 32 }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:30:00+0000', name: 'Anne', age: 32 }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:45:00+0000', name: 'Anne', age: 32 }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T15:45:00+0000', name: 'Anne', age: 32 }]

const newArray = data.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    const
        end = new Date(Date.parse(current.timestamp) + 15 * 60 * 1000).toISOString(),
        item = accumulator.find(o =>
            o.name === current.name &&
            o.end === new Date(current.timestamp).toISOString()
        );
    
    if (item) item.end = end;
    else accumulator.push({ ...current, end });

    return accumulator;
}, [])

console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to get the required result as in your own code, but we can make a slight change to update the lastItem in the accumulator array if

- The names are the same (lastItem.name === name)
- The dates are within 15 minutes

If this condition isn't met we simply add to the accumulator array.

```js
const data = [ { timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:15:00+0000', name: 'John', age: 25, }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:30:00+0000', name: 'John', age: 25, }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:45:00+0000', name: 'John', age: 25, }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T15:45:00+0000', name: 'John', age: 25, }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:15:00+0000', name: 'Anne', age: 32, }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:30:00+0000', name: 'Anne', age: 32, }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T14:45:00+0000', name: 'Anne', age: 32, }, { timestamp: '2021-11-23T15:45:00+0000', name: 'Anne', age: 32, }, ] 
    
const result = data.reduce((acc, { timestamp, name, age }) => { 
    let lastItem = acc[acc.length - 1];
    let end = new Date(Date.parse(timestamp) + 15*60*1000);
    
    // If the current row matches just update the end time
    if (lastItem && lastItem.name === name && (Date.parse(lastItem.end) - Date.parse(timestamp) >= 0)) { 
        lastItem.end = end;
    } else {
        acc.push({ timestamp, name, age, end });
    } 
    return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```